# Slick insert from select

Tags: scala, slick

I use scala 2.11 and slick 2.1.0 and have a compiled code:

```
   trait TSegmentClient { this: Profile =>

        import profile.simple._

        class SegmentClients(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Long)](tag, "seg") {

            def segmentId = column[Int]("segment_id")
            def clientId = column[Long]("client_id")

            def * = (segmentId, clientId)
        }
    }

    segmentClients.insert(clientBehaviors.map(c => (1, c.clientId)))
```

it works.

But i need a case class like this:

```
case class SegmentClient(segmentId: Int, clientId: Long)

trait TSegmentClient { this: Profile =>

    import profile.simple._

    class SegmentClients(tag: Tag) extends Table[SegmentClient](tag, "seg") {

        def segmentId = column[Int]("segment_id")
        def clientId = column[Long]("client_id")

        def * = (segmentId, clientId) <> (SegmentClient.tupled, SegmentClient.unapply)
    }
}

segmentClients.insert(clientBehaviors.map(c => (1, c.clientId)))
```

But it doesn't compile.

> (value: models.coper.datamining.SegmentClient)(implicit session:
>   scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef)Int cannot be applied to
>   (scala.slick.lifted.Query[(scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int],
>   scala.slick.lifted.Column[Long]),(Int, Long),Seq])
>                  segmentClients.insert(clientBehaviors.map(c => (segmentId, c.clientId)))

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: how about         def tuple = (segmentId, clientId);         def * = tuple <> (SegmentClient.tupled, SegmentClient.unapply);     and segmentClients.tuple.insert(...) ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. In my sample 2 i need to change `def * = (segmentId, clientId) <> (SegmentClient.tupled, SegmentClient.unapply)` to `tuple = (segmentId, clientId); def * = tuple <> (SegmentClient.tupled, SegmentClient.unapply)` and after that do `segmentClients.tuple.insert(clientBehaviors.map(c => (1, c.clientId)))` ? Compiler says, that value tuple is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery

Comment: my mistake, use: segmentClients.map(_.tuple).insert(...)

Comment: Greate! It works, thanks! Please add your answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using another projection to a tuple that is not mapped to a case class.

```
case class SegmentClient(segmentId: Int, clientId: Long)

trait TSegmentClient { this: Profile =>

    import profile.simple._

    class SegmentClients(tag: Tag) extends Table[SegmentClient](tag, "seg") {

        def segmentId = column[Int]("segment_id")
        def clientId = column[Long]("client_id")
        def tuple = (segmentId, clientId) 
        def * = tuple <> (SegmentClient.tupled, SegmentClient.unapply)
    }
}

segmentClients.map(_.tuple).insert(clientBehaviors.map(c => (1, c.clientId)))
```

Comment: Hey @cvogt. What's the right way to do this in slick 3+?

Comment: try forceInsertQuery. 

See the last part of [this doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#inserting)

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` method on `segmentClients` in your second example  expects a `SegmentClient` instance  since `SegmentClients` is a [mapped table](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/lifted-embedding.html#mapped-tables). That's what the compiler error message is basically saying. I don't know whether there's a more idiomatic approach, since I don't know Slick too well, but as a workaround you could also use:

```
val behaviours = clientBehaviours.list.map(c => SegmentClient(1, c.clientId))
segmentClients.insertAll(behaviours)
```

Comment: your code not compiled, i can do it like this: `for (c <- clientBehaviours.list) yield segmentClients.insert(new SegmentClient(1, c.clientId))` but it very slowly. I need one request to execute on server side

Comment: SegmentClient need Int, Long, but c.clientId is a scala.slick.lifted.Column[Long]

Comment: Having a `Column` for `c.clientId` means that you are still inside a query, but `list` is supposed to return a `List` of whatever the `ClientBehaviour` table is mapped to. Can you also post what type `clientBehaviours` actually is. Maybe I miss something, but it seems like as if you didn't call `list`. And did you already try out what cvogt suggested?